# Creating a filter for 301 redirects in htaccess for a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to create a redirect from `http://www.domain.com/default/*` to `http://www.domain.com/*`

This is because I am developing a new site for a client that was using some odd CMS that put every url in a /default/ folder. The new CMS, wordpress, obviously does not. How does one go about creating this rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple `mod_alias` based rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/default/(.*)$ /$1
```

OR using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^defult/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```